# Rails 4 -No route matches, route is defined. Only occurs in testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, path, get, routes

So I am following Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and I am on chapter 5 (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout).

When I run the final test that he adds for the sign up link:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get new" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

I get this error when I run the test:

```
ERROR["test_should_get_new", UsersControllerTest, 2016-07-01 17:48:25 +0100]
 test_should_get_new#UsersControllerTest (1467391705.83s)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:         ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/signup", :controller=>"users"}
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

Here is the routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

end
```

I have used the signup_path helper in the views as a link and they work fine.

Why is test trying to access an action called "/signup" when I have defined in the routes that "signup" should become the new action in the users controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a controller test (rather than feature test), your controller shouldn't care which url you visited. Therefore, `get` expects an action, not a path.

Change

```
get signup_path
```

to

```
get :new
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the route, you can modify your test case to  following.

1. `assert_generates` asserts that a particular option generate a particular path.
   `assert_generates '/signup', {controller: 'users', action: 'new'}`

---

2. `assert_recognizes` is the reverse of `assert_generates`. It asserts that a given path is recognized and routes it to a particular spot in your application.

   `assert_recognizes({ controller: 'users', action: 'new'}, '/signup')`

---

3. The `assert_routing` assertion checks the route both ways: it tests that the path generates the options, and that the options generate the path. Thus, it combines the functions of `assert_generates` and `assert_recognizes`.

   `assert_routing({ path: 'signup', method: :get }, { controller: 'users', action: 'new' })`